# Issues compiling vmware web api client code into useable objects

Tags: c++, vmware, gsoap

I'm using vmware's web [application api](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/) in an attempt just to simply retrieve the fields in the "ServiceContent" object. There is an example of how this should be accomplished located at the [vmware forum](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/200348). The example contained there compiles fine for me however I get segfaults when running the simple example - specifically the trace goes back to the soap_serializeheader() function (I believe these are defined in stdsoap2.cpp). **My problem is that I do not know how to avoid this segfault and have no idea why this is occurring (as I am following the example almost word for word)**. I am using OS X tool chain (gcc version 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465) ) combined with (gsoap release 2.7.16). I tried gsoap 2.8 but got the same result. Below is the procedure I used to get to where I am now.

These are the commands I used to parse the wsdl:

```
wsdl2h -o vim25.h vimService.wsdl
```

Once this is parsed, I compiled using the following command:

```
soapcpp2 -x -C -pvsp vim25.h -I/place/where/stlvector.h/is
```

this generates files vspC.cpp, vspClient.cpp, and vspVimBindingProxy.cpp. Internally these files have the same prefixes for functions (i.e. ns1/ns2 etc) so my calls are the same as those in the example.

This is the command I am using to compile vspC.cpp and vspClient.cpp:

```
g++ -DWITH_COOKIES -DWITH_OPENSSL -c vspC.cpp
g++ -DWITH_COOKIES -DWITH_OPENSSL -c vspClient.cpp
```

This is the command I use to compile stdsoap2.cpp (if I do not compile with -DWITH_NONAMESPACES I get an error about an undefined symbol "_namepspaces" when I link everything):

```
g++ -DWITH_COOKIES -DWITH_OPENSSL -DWITH_NONAMESPACES -c stdsoap2.cpp
```

I then link everything together with the test code (again this is copied almost identically from the example, just with the changes to correctly refer to the files I created):

```
g++ -DWITH_COOKIES -DWITH_OPENSSL vspC.o vcpClient.o stdsoap2.o testcase.cpp -lssl -lcrypto -o doesntwork
```

This compiles correctly, but of course fails to run. I read about an OS X user in this [vmware forum post](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1523753) who was also having trouble. It *appears* the [gsoap guide](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.33) says you cannot use stdsoap2.cpp's header and fault serialization codes, and you must compile them separately. The user in the [OS X post](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1523753) seems to have done this, however I am not sure how to incorporate them into my test file (he creates the empty env.h file and then compiles it with soap2cpp) - if I include the envH.h file i get about naming conflicts with vspH.h. **So a second question would be how do I use soap2cpp to compile all the stubs correctly so that there are not namespace conflicts** (which is what I appear to be encountering).

I will not provide the source, as it is displayed at the first [vwmare forum link](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/200348) by user stumpr. I do not believe **the issue is in** the source, but in **the way I have used either wsdl2h, soap2cpp, or some incorrect combination of flags during compilation with g++.**

Thanks for taking a look, and hopefully some one can resolve the issue!

**EDIT** I think I may have solved this - by using a 64bit system (and one with more memory). I tried compiling with -m32 on the X.6 and it was not able to do it (complaining about memory issues).

Hopefully someone will stumble upon this and be happy to know the answer.